# 2D integral with a step function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I would like to understand how the following two integrals are taken:
$$
I_\infty(n,m)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{d}\xi \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{d}\xi'\epsilon(\xi-\xi')\operatorname{e}^{i(n\xi+m\xi')}
$$
$$
I_\pi(n,m)=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{d}\xi \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{d}\xi'\epsilon(\xi-\xi')\operatorname{e}^{i(n\xi+m\xi')}
$$
where
$$
\epsilon(\xi)=1-2\theta(\xi)
$$
is the antisymmetric step function.

I know the answer for the second case but don't know how to derive it:
[image]

I guess one should change variables to $t=\xi-\xi'$ and $s=\xi+\xi'$, which leads to something like $\int \epsilon(r) \operatorname{d}r \operatorname{e}^{ir(n-m)/2}\int \operatorname{d}s \operatorname{e}^{is(n+m)/2}$. The second integral gives the desired delta but I'm not sure about the first one.

Comment: What is the complete definition of $\theta(\xi)$? Is it $\theta(\xi)=1$ for $\xi\geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: I think it's $1/2$ for $0$.

Comment: @mavzolj Ok, anyway the value of $\theta$ at $0$ does not change the integral

Answer (score 2):

By the definition, $\epsilon(t)=-1$ for $t> 0$ and $\epsilon(t)=1$ for $t<0$. It follows that
$$\begin{align}
I_\pi(n,m)&=-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx \int_{-\pi}^{x}e^{i(nx+my)}dy+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx \int_{x}^{\pi}e^{i(nx+my)}dy\\
&=-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}dx \int_{-\pi}^{x}e^{imy}dy+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}dx \int_{x}^{\pi}e^{imy}dy\\
&=-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{imy}dy \int_{y}^{\pi}e^{inx}dx+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}dx \int_{x}^{\pi}e^{imy}dy\\
&=-A(m,n)+A(n,m).
\end{align}$$
Hence, if $m\not=0$ and $n\not=0$ then
$$\begin{align}
A(n,m)&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}dx \int_{x}^{\pi}e^{imy}dy
=\frac{1}{im}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}((-1)^m-e^{imx})dx\\
&=\frac{i}{m}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(m+n)x}dx=
\frac{2\pi i}{m}\delta_{m,-n}
\end{align}
$$
and therefore
$$I_\pi(n,m)=-A(m,n)+A(n,m)=
-\frac{2\pi i}{n}\delta_{-n,m}+\frac{2\pi i}{m}\delta_{m,-n}
=-\frac{4\pi i}{n}\delta_{m,-n}.$$
Can you handle the other cases?

P.S. Note that
$$A(m,n)+A(n,m)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}dx\cdot\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{imy}dy=4\pi^2\delta_{n,0}\,\delta_{m,0}.$$

Comment: Thank you, understood this one. It is not entirely clear to me how to handle the $(-1)^m$ term in the $\infty$ case but assuming that it cancels out, the final answer seems to be identical upon replacing $\delta_{m,-n}\to\delta(m+n)$.